# Multiply Rectangular Matrices in CUDA

Tags: cuda

In this homework i need to complete the code to multiply two rectangle matrices using CUDA C. After I completed the code, I submitted and the solution was correct for the data set when the matrices were square, while the result wasn't matching the expected value when the matrices were not square.

Here is the code after I added the missing parts:

```
#include    <wb.h>

#define wbCheck(stmt) do {                             \
    cudaError_t err = stmt;                            \
    if (err != cudaSuccess) {                          \
        wbLog(ERROR, "Failed to run stmt ", #stmt);    \
        return -1;                                     \
    }                                                  \
} while(0)

// Compute C = A * B
__global__ void matrixMultiply(float * A, float * B, float * C,
               int numARows, int numAColumns,
               int numBRows, int numBColumns,
               int numCRows, int numCColumns) {
   //@@ Insert code to implement matrix multiplication here
   int Row = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
   int Col = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
   if (numAColumns != numBRows) return ;
   if ((Row < numARows) && (Col < numBColumns)){
       float Cvalue = 0;
       for (int k = 0 ; k < numAColumns ; ++k )
       Cvalue += A[Row*numAColumns + k] * B[k * numBRows + Col];
       C[Row*numAColumns + Col] = Cvalue;
     }

    }



int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
   wbArg_t args;
   float * hostA; // The A matrix
   float * hostB; // The B matrix
   float * hostC; // The output C matrix
   float * deviceA;
   float * deviceB;
   float * deviceC;
   int numARows; // number of rows in the matrix A
   int numAColumns; // number of columns in the matrix A
   int numBRows; // number of rows in the matrix B
   int numBColumns; // number of columns in the matrix B
   int numCRows; // number of rows in the matrix C (you have to set this)
   int numCColumns; // number of columns in the matrix C (you have to set this)

   args = wbArg_read(argc, argv);

   wbTime_start(Generic, "Importing data and creating memory on host");
   hostA = (float *) wbImport(wbArg_getInputFile(args, 0), &numARows, &numAColumns);
   hostB = (float *) wbImport(wbArg_getInputFile(args, 1), &numBRows, &numBColumns);
   //@@ Set numCRows and numCColumns  
   numCRows = 0;
   numCColumns = 0;
   numCRows = numARows;
   numCColumns = numBColumns;  
   //@@ Allocate the hostC matrix
   hostC = (float*) malloc(sizeof(float)*numCRows*numCColumns);  
   wbTime_stop(Generic, "Importing data and creating memory on host");

   wbLog(TRACE, "The dimensions of A are ", numARows, " x ", numAColumns);
   wbLog(TRACE, "The dimensions of B are ", numBRows, " x ", numBColumns);

   wbTime_start(GPU, "Allocating GPU memory.");
   //@@ Allocate GPU memory here
   cudaMalloc((void**)&deviceA ,sizeof(float)*numARows*numAColumns );
   cudaMalloc((void**)&deviceB , sizeof(float)*numBRows*numBColumns);
   cudaMalloc((void**)&deviceC , sizeof(float)*numCRows*numCColumns);  

   wbTime_stop(GPU, "Allocating GPU memory.");

   wbTime_start(GPU, "Copying input memory to the GPU.");
   //@@ Copy memory to the GPU here

   cudaMemcpy(deviceA, hostA, sizeof(float)*numARows*numAColumns, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
   cudaMemcpy(deviceB, hostB, sizeof(float)*numBRows*numBColumns, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
   wbTime_stop(GPU, "Copying input memory to the GPU.");

   //@@ Initialize the grid and block dimensions here

   dim3 DimGrid(numARows / 8 , numBColumns / 8, 1);
   dim3 DimBlock(8 , 8, 1);

   wbTime_start(Compute, "Performing CUDA computation");

   //@@ Launch the GPU Kernel here
   matrixMultiply<<<DimGrid , DimBlock>>>(deviceA , deviceB , deviceC , numARows , numAColumns, numBRows ,numBColumns , numCRows , numCColumns);  

   cudaThreadSynchronize();
   wbTime_stop(Compute, "Performing CUDA computation");

   wbTime_start(Copy, "Copying output memory to the CPU");
   //@@ Copy the GPU memory back to the CPU here
   cudaMemcpy(hostC, deviceC, sizeof(float)*numCRows*numCColumns , cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);  

   wbTime_stop(Copy, "Copying output memory to the CPU");

   wbTime_start(GPU, "Freeing GPU Memory");
   //@@ Free the GPU memory here

   cudaFree(deviceA);
   cudaFree(deviceB);
   cudaFree(deviceC);
   wbTime_stop(GPU, "Freeing GPU Memory");

   wbSolution(args, hostC, numCRows, numCColumns);

   free(hostA);
   free(hostB);
   free(hostC);

   return 0;
}
```

I hope you can help me to find which part is incorrect.

Answer (score 4):

After the help of Ira, Ahmad, ram, and Oli Fly, I got the correct answer as follows:

```
#include    <wb.h>

#define wbCheck(stmt) do {                                 \
        cudaError_t err = stmt;                            \
        if (err != cudaSuccess) {                          \
            wbLog(ERROR, "Failed to run stmt ", #stmt);    \
            return -1;                                     \
        }                                                  \
    } while(0)

// Compute C = A * B
__global__ void matrixMultiply(float * A, float * B, float * C,
                   int numARows, int numAColumns,
                   int numBRows, int numBColumns,
                   int numCRows, int numCColumns) {
    //@@ Insert code to implement matrix multiplication here
    int Row = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
    int Col = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    if (numAColumns != numBRows) return;
    if ((Row < numARows) && (Col < numBColumns)){
    float Cvalue = 0;
    for (int k = 0; k < numAColumns; ++k)
    Cvalue += A[Row*numAColumns + k] * B[k * numBColumns + Col];
    C[Row*numCColumns + Col] = Cvalue;
  }

}

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    wbArg_t args;
    float * hostA; // The A matrix
    float * hostB; // The B matrix
    float * hostC; // The output C matrix
    float * deviceA;
    float * deviceB;
    float * deviceC;
    int numARows; // number of rows in the matrix A
    int numAColumns; // number of columns in the matrix A
    int numBRows; // number of rows in the matrix B
    int numBColumns; // number of columns in the matrix B
    int numCRows; // number of rows in the matrix C (you have to set this)
    int numCColumns; // number of columns in the matrix C (you have to set this)

    args = wbArg_read(argc, argv);

    wbTime_start(Generic, "Importing data and creating memory on host");
    hostA = (float *) wbImport(wbArg_getInputFile(args, 0), &numARows, &numAColumns);
    hostB = (float *) wbImport(wbArg_getInputFile(args, 1), &numBRows, &numBColumns);
    //@@ Set numCRows and numCColumns  
    numCRows = 0;
    numCColumns = 0;
    numCRows = numARows;
    numCColumns = numBColumns;  
    //@@ Allocate the hostC matrix
    hostC = (float*) malloc(sizeof(float)*numCRows*numCColumns);  
    wbTime_stop(Generic, "Importing data and creating memory on host");

    wbLog(TRACE, "The dimensions of A are ", numARows, " x ", numAColumns);
    wbLog(TRACE, "The dimensions of B are ", numBRows, " x ", numBColumns);

    wbTime_start(GPU, "Allocating GPU memory.");
    //@@ Allocate GPU memory here
    cudaMalloc((void**)&deviceA ,sizeof(float)*numARows*numAColumns );
    cudaMalloc((void**)&deviceB , sizeof(float)*numBRows*numBColumns);
    cudaMalloc((void**)&deviceC , sizeof(float)*numCRows*numCColumns);  

    wbTime_stop(GPU, "Allocating GPU memory.");

    wbTime_start(GPU, "Copying input memory to the GPU.");
    //@@ Copy memory to the GPU here

    cudaMemcpy(deviceA, hostA, sizeof(float)*numARows*numAColumns, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(deviceB, hostB, sizeof(float)*numBRows*numBColumns, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    wbTime_stop(GPU, "Copying input memory to the GPU.");

    //@@ Initialize the grid and block dimensions here

    dim3 DimGrid((numCColumns - 1) / 8 + 1, (numCRows - 1) / 8 + 1, 1);
    dim3 DimBlock(8 , 8, 1);

    wbTime_start(Compute, "Performing CUDA computation");

    //@@ Launch the GPU Kernel here
    matrixMultiply<<<DimGrid , DimBlock>>>(deviceA , deviceB , deviceC , numARows , numAColumns, numBRows ,numBColumns , numCRows , numCColumns);  

    cudaThreadSynchronize();
    wbTime_stop(Compute, "Performing CUDA computation");

    wbTime_start(Copy, "Copying output memory to the CPU");
    //@@ Copy the GPU memory back to the CPU here
    cudaMemcpy(hostC, deviceC, sizeof(float)*numCRows*numCColumns , cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);  

    wbTime_stop(Copy, "Copying output memory to the CPU");

    wbTime_start(GPU, "Freeing GPU Memory");
    //@@ Free the GPU memory here

    cudaFree(deviceA);
    cudaFree(deviceB);
    cudaFree(deviceC);
    wbTime_stop(GPU, "Freeing GPU Memory");

    wbSolution(args, hostC, numCRows, numCColumns);

    free(hostA);
    free(hostB);
    free(hostC);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for asking this question. It really helped me out. One thing I would like to ask, did you ever get it working for Datasets where the dimensions of the Matrix are NOT multiples of 8?

Comment: @ Abraham , some of the data sets were with the following dimensions: (the dimensions of matrix A is 200*100 , dimensions of Matrix B is 100*256 ) and there was another data set (dimensions of A is 100*128 , dimensions of B is 128*50)

Comment: I believe the answer for #2 is wrong with this code because one of the dimensions (100) is not evenly divisible by the block size (8).  The setup of the grid doesn't account for that.

Comment: This is a void function, how can it return something?

Comment: @LeifWickland , i am not that expertise in Cuda parallel programming , but i had tried this code on some data sets and was returning a correct result , now the important is to reduce the execution time , and here i can't say that this code is the best , so if in both cases (the correctness of the code and for better execution time ) feel free please to suggest a modulation so it will be useful for all the community , thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Replace :
    `for (int k = 0 ; k < numAColumns ; ++k )
       Cvalue += A[Row*numAColumns + k] * B[k * numBRows + Col];
       C[Row*numAColumns + Col] = Cvalue; 
     }`

with
    `for (int k = 0 ; k < numAColumns ; ++k )
       Cvalue += A[Row*numAColumns + k] * B[k * numBColumns + Col];
       C[Row*numCColumns + Col] = Cvalue;
     }`

Comment: thank you Ira , with your suggestion i got one more set of data to be correct , but i still not able to get fully expected result for all the data sets, for example i got this case : The solution did not match the expected results at column 200 and row 0. Expecting 415.556 but got 0.807 .  I  think that you are right it is something in the function matrixMultiply.

Answer (score 2):

Replace :

```
Cvalue += A[Row*numAColumns + k] * B[k * numBRows + Col];
```

with

```
Cvalue += A[Row*numAColumns + k] * B[k * numBColumns + Col];
```

Comment: hi Ahmad , thank you for trying to help me to find which part is incorrect , and after following your advice , i found that the processing time was much better , but the result still not the expected result for example one data set show that :The solution did not match the expected results at column 124 and row 0. Expecting 457.153 but got 422.296. now i agree with you has to be some mistake in the function matrixMultiply , maybe i need to change some other thing .

Answer (score 2):

replace

```
Cvalue += A[Row*numAColumns + k] * B[k * numBRows + Col];
```

for

```
Cvalue += A[Row*numAColumns +k]* B[k*numBColumns+Col];
```

and

```
C[Row*numAColumns + Col] = Cvalue;
```

for

```
C[Row*numCColumns+Col] = Cvalue;
```

Comment: thanks ram , your corrections are true ,they are similar to the one Ahmad and Ira mentioned before , even i made those corrections , but still i can't get the right the result .

Answer (score 1):

we can use tiled matrix multiplication and i found it has a better execution time .

```
#include    <wb.h>

#define wbCheck(stmt) do {                                 \
        cudaError_t err = stmt;                            \
        if (err != cudaSuccess) {                          \
            wbLog(ERROR, "Failed to run stmt ", #stmt);    \
            return -1;                                     \
        }                                                  \
    } while(0)

// Compute C = A * B
__global__ void matrixMultiplyShared(float * A, float * B, float * C,
                             int numARows, int numAColumns,
                             int numBRows, int numBColumns,
                             int numCRows, int numCColumns) {
    //@@ Insert code to implement matrix multiplication here
    //@@ You have to use shared memory for this MP
    const int TILE_WIDTH = 32;
     __shared__ float sharedA[TILE_WIDTH][TILE_WIDTH];
     __shared__ float sharedB[TILE_WIDTH][TILE_WIDTH];
    int bx = blockIdx.x;
    int by = blockIdx.y;
    int tx = threadIdx.x;
    int ty = threadIdx.y;
    int Row = by*TILE_WIDTH + ty;
    int Col = bx*TILE_WIDTH + tx;
    float Cvalue = 0.0; 
    if (numAColumns != numBRows) return ;
    for (int i = 0; i < (int)(ceil((float)numAColumns/TILE_WIDTH)); i++)
    {

      if (i*TILE_WIDTH + tx < numAColumns && Row < numARows){
            sharedA[ty][tx] = A[Row*numAColumns + i*TILE_WIDTH + tx];
      }else{
            sharedA[ty][tx] = 0.0;
      }

      if (i*TILE_WIDTH + ty < numBRows && Col < numBColumns){
            sharedB[ty][tx] = B[(i*TILE_WIDTH + ty)*numBColumns + Col];
      }else{
            sharedB[ty][tx] = 0.0;
      }
       __syncthreads();
         if(Row < numARows && Col < numBColumns){

            for(int j = 0; j < TILE_WIDTH; j++)
            Cvalue += sharedA[ty][j] * sharedB[j][tx];
      }

        __syncthreads();
    }

    if (Row < numCRows && Col < numCColumns)
        C[Row*numCColumns + Col] = Cvalue;
}    




int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    wbArg_t args;
    float * hostA; // The A matrix
    float * hostB; // The B matrix
    float * hostC; // The output C matrix
    float * deviceA;
    float * deviceB;
    float * deviceC;
    int numARows; // number of rows in the matrix A
    int numAColumns; // number of columns in the matrix A
    int numBRows; // number of rows in the matrix B
    int numBColumns; // number of columns in the matrix B
    int numCRows; // number of rows in the matrix C (you have to set this)
    int numCColumns; // number of columns in the matrix C (you have to set this)
    int TILE_WIDTH = 32;

    args = wbArg_read(argc, argv);

    wbTime_start(Generic, "Importing data and creating memory on host");
    hostA = (float *) wbImport(wbArg_getInputFile(args, 0), &numARows, &numAColumns);
    hostB = (float *) wbImport(wbArg_getInputFile(args, 1), &numBRows, &numBColumns);
    //@@ Set numCRows and numCColumns
    numCRows = 0;
    numCColumns = 0;
    numCRows = numARows;
    numCColumns = numBColumns;
    //@@ Allocate the hostC matrix
    hostC = (float*) malloc(sizeof(float)*numCRows*numCColumns);  
    wbTime_stop(Generic, "Importing data and creating memory on host");

    wbLog(TRACE, "The dimensions of A are ", numARows, " x ", numAColumns);
    wbLog(TRACE, "The dimensions of B are ", numBRows, " x ", numBColumns);

    wbTime_start(GPU, "Allocating GPU memory.");
    //@@ Allocate GPU memory here
    cudaMalloc((void**)&deviceA , sizeof(float)*numARows*numAColumns );
    cudaMalloc((void**)&deviceB , sizeof(float)*numBRows*numBColumns);
    cudaMalloc((void**)&deviceC , sizeof(float)*numCRows*numCColumns);  

    wbTime_stop(GPU, "Allocating GPU memory.");

    wbTime_start(GPU, "Copying input memory to the GPU.");
    //@@ Copy memory to the GPU here
    cudaMemcpy(deviceA, hostA, sizeof(float)*numARows*numAColumns,    cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(deviceB, hostB, sizeof(float)*numBRows*numBColumns, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);  

    wbTime_stop(GPU, "Copying input memory to the GPU.");

    //@@ Initialize the grid and block dimensions here
    int dimX = (int)(ceil((float)numCColumns / TILE_WIDTH));  
    int dimY = (int)(ceil((float)numCRows / TILE_WIDTH));
    dim3 DimGrid(dimX, dimY);
    dim3 DimBlock(TILE_WIDTH, TILE_WIDTH);



    wbTime_start(Compute, "Performing CUDA computation");
    //@@ Launch the GPU Kernel here
    matrixMultiplyShared<<<DimGrid , DimBlock>>>(deviceA , deviceB , deviceC , numARows , numAColumns, numBRows ,numBColumns , numCRows , numCColumns);  

    cudaThreadSynchronize();
    wbTime_stop(Compute, "Performing CUDA computation");

    wbTime_start(Copy, "Copying output memory to the CPU");
    //@@ Copy the GPU memory back to the CPU here
    cudaMemcpy(hostC, deviceC, sizeof(float)*numCRows*numCColumns , cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);  

    wbTime_stop(Copy, "Copying output memory to the CPU");

    wbTime_start(GPU, "Freeing GPU Memory");
    //@@ Free the GPU memory here
    cudaFree(deviceA);
    cudaFree(deviceB);
    cudaFree(deviceC);  

    wbTime_stop(GPU, "Freeing GPU Memory");

    wbSolution(args, hostC, numCRows, numCColumns);

    free(hostA);
    free(hostB);
    free(hostC);

    return 0;
}
```