# CUDA Matrix Multiplication: Outputting Zero

Tags: cuda, matrix-multiplication

Trying to run a program to do Matrix Multiplication in CUDA. I think I have everything set up correctly and the program runs and executes. Problem is the output. Anyone see whats wrong with my code? Appearently the output matrix has a value of 0 no matter what the inputs are. I think the issue is that i have to convert from using int Width as a parameter in the Kernal function to using the number of rows/columns instead. I didnt think would/should be a problem but something is going wrong... Thanks for the help!

```
#define TILE_WIDTH 16

// Compute C = A * B
__global__ void matrixMultiply(float * A, float * B, float * C,
               int numARows, int numAColumns,
               int numBRows, int numBColumns,
               int numCRows, int numCColumns) 
{
    //@@ Insert code to implement matrix multiplication here
    float Cvalue = 0.0;
    int Row = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
    int Col = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;

    if ((Row < numCRows) && (Col < numCColumns)) 
    {       
        float Pvalue = 0;
        for (int k = 0; k < numCRows; ++k) Pvalue += A[Row*numCColumns+k] * B[k*numCRows+Col];
        C[Row*numCRows+Col] = Cvalue;
    }

}

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
wbArg_t args;
float * hostA; // The A matrix
float * hostB; // The B matrix
float * hostC; // The output C matrix
float * deviceA;
float * deviceB;
float * deviceC;
int numARows; // number of rows in the matrix A
int numAColumns; // number of columns in the matrix A
int numBRows; // number of rows in the matrix B
int numBColumns; // number of columns in the matrix B
int numCRows; // number of rows in the matrix C (you have to set this)
int numCColumns; // number of columns in the matrix C (you have to set this)

args = wbArg_read(argc, argv);
wbTime_start(Generic, "Importing data and creating memory on host");
hostA = (float *) wbImport(wbArg_getInputFile(args, 0), &numARows, &numAColumns);
hostB = (float *) wbImport(wbArg_getInputFile(args, 1), &numBRows, &numBColumns);
//@@ Set numCRows and numCColumns
numCRows = numBRows;
numCColumns = numAColumns;  
int sizeA = numARows * numAColumns * sizeof(float);
int sizeB = numBRows * numBColumns * sizeof(float);
int sizeC = numCRows * numCColumns * sizeof(float);
//@@ Allocate the hostC matrix
hostC = (float *) malloc(sizeC);
wbTime_stop(Generic, "Importing data and creating memory on host");

wbLog(TRACE, "The dimensions of A are ", numARows, " x ", numAColumns);
wbLog(TRACE, "The dimensions of B are ", numBRows, " x ", numBColumns);

wbTime_start(GPU, "Allocating GPU memory.");
//@@ Allocate GPU memory here
cudaMalloc((void **) &deviceA, sizeA);      
cudaMalloc((void **) &deviceB, sizeB);
cudaMalloc((void **) &deviceC, sizeC);
wbTime_stop(GPU, "Allocating GPU memory.");

wbTime_start(GPU, "Copying input memory to the GPU.");
//@@ Copy memory to the GPU here
cudaMemcpy(deviceA, hostA, sizeA, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
cudaMemcpy(deviceB, hostB, sizeB, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
wbTime_stop(GPU, "Copying input memory to the GPU.");

//@@ Initialize the grid and block dimensions here
dim3 dimGrid(numCRows/TILE_WIDTH, numCColumns/TILE_sWIDTH, 1);
dim3 dimBlock(TILE_WIDTH, TILE_WIDTH, 1);

wbTime_start(Compute, "Performing CUDA computation");
//@@ Launch the GPU Kernel here
matrixMultiply<<<dimGrid,dimBlock>>>(deviceA, deviceB, deviceC,
                                        numARows, numAColumns,
                                        numBRows, numBColumns,
                                        numCRows, numCColumns);
cudaThreadSynchronize();
wbTime_stop(Compute, "Performing CUDA computation");

wbTime_start(Copy, "Copying output memory to the CPU");
//@@ Copy the GPU memory back to the CPU here      
cudaMemcpy(hostC, deviceC, sizeC, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
wbTime_stop(Copy, "Copying output memory to the CPU");

wbTime_start(GPU, "Freeing GPU Memory");
//@@ Free the GPU memory here    
cudaFree(deviceA);
cudaFree(deviceB);
cudaFree(deviceC);
wbTime_stop(GPU, "Freeing GPU Memory");

wbSolution(args, hostC, numCRows, numCColumns);

free(hostA);
free(hostB);
free(hostC);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [multiply rectangular matrices kernel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13896560/multiply-rectangular-matrices-kernel)

Comment: This coursera question has been asked at least 3 times already in recent days.

Comment: K well it didnt show up in my search didnt need the sass. thanks anyway. also technically im not allowed to just take straight up answers but w.e

Comment: i guess sometimes you have to actually have to read the issue and then the code and the answer jumps out at you.

Answer (score 1):

Okay so the reason it was returning zero was because my results were never being saved into my output matrix cause my code has saving in a unused, but initialized, value over and over again through the loop. Also i screwed up the numCRows and numCColumns values but that was more readily identifiably after my code started to actually run.

```
__global__ void matrixMultiply(float * A, float * B, float * C,
               int numARows, int numAColumns,
               int numBRows, int numBColumns,
               int numCRows, int numCColumns) 
{
    //@@ Insert code to implement matrix multiplication here
    int Row = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
    int Col = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;

    if ((Row < numCRows) && (Col < numCColumns)) 
    {       
        float Cvalue = 0;
        for (int k = 0; k < numCRows; ++k) 
        {
          Cvalue += A[Row*numAColumns+k] * B[k*numBColumns+Col];
        }
          C[Row*numCColumns+Col] = Cvalue;
    }

}
```

Also in the main code:

```
numCRows = numARows;
numCColumns = numBColumns;
```