# Rectangular matrix multiplication in cuda

Tags: matrix, cuda

i am doing rectangular matrix multiplication in `cuda`, but i cant able to launch the kernel with proper grid and block size. i tried with many configuration. My matrix sizes are `189*1024` and `1024*100`.

Anyone can help me to come out of this problem?.

```
__global__ void matrixMultiply(float * C, float * A, float * B,
                   int numARows, int numAColumns,
                   int numBRows, int numBColumns,
                   int numCRows, int numCColumns) {
    //@@ Insert code to implement matrix multiplication here
    int Row = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
    int Col = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    if (numAColumns != numBRows) return;
    if ((Row < numARows) && (Col < numBColumns)){
    float Cvalue = 0;
    for (int k = 0; k < numAColumns; ++k)
    Cvalue += A[Row*numAColumns + k] * B[k * numBColumns + Col];
    C[Row*numCColumns + Col] = Cvalue;
  }

}
```

this is the global function am using
and gridsize is numCColumns/8 numCRow/8
    blocksize is [ 8 8]

Comment: You need to provide a small, complete reproducer to help you. You say you are not able to launch. whats the error ?

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13903229/2386951) post. Your question is an exact copy of it.

Comment: I checked that post also....Am loading cuda kernel using matlab....
and I got the answer,thanks for your comment...